# Infinity in logic implicit (compact) notation.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra

This question is about notation.

Is this true?

$$\bigvee_{i=1}^{\infty}~p_{i} \Longleftrightarrow \bigvee_{i=1}^{}~p_{i}$$

I mean, will it represent the same if I write $\infty$ or left it blank on top of  $\bigwedge$ and $\bigvee$ ?

Comment: I'm not really certain about what you question is. However, maybe as a pointer, there are classes of logics incorporating infinite applications of operators into their language. These are called infinitary logics and common propositional infinitary logic has the capability to express infinite conjunctions and disjunctions much like the left part of you expression. Maybe check out https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-infinitary/

Comment: @zzuussee Question: Will it represent same if I write $\infty$ or left it blank on top of  $\bigwedge$ and $\bigvee$ ?

Comment: Well, this is more a question of notation, however I think leaving it blank is uncommon practice. As all $i$ range over the naturals (without $0$), it is also common to write $\bigwedge_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$. Leaving it blank would lead me at least to think(without further context) that you just take $i=1$.

Comment: Notation doesn't have an absolute meaning. We use it in order to communicate more efficiently. With any notation, your primary goal should be to make the intended meaning clear. If there's any concern that your reader might not understand your notational convention, either (1) don't use it, or (2) explain it clearly in words before you use it for the first time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the notation "$\bigvee_{i=1}p_i$" is noticeably less clear than the other. Another option would be "$\bigvee_{i\ge 1}p_i$" if you really want to avoid upper bounds for some reason.

Ultimately, I don't see why you wouldn't put in upper bounds: it makes things more clear and doesn't add any real length or complexity notation-wise.

---

For what it's worth, I personally prefer $$\bigvee_{i\in\mathbb{N}}p_i$$ since there are times index sets other than $\mathbb{N}$ are used (say, $\mathbb{R}$). But this is definitely an ideosyncracy of mine: "$\bigvee_{i=1}^\infty p_i$" is fully unambiguous in my opinion *(if $i$ were intended to range over reals, I think "$\bigvee_{i\in [1,\infty)}p_i$" would be used instead)*.

Comment: $\mathbb{N}$ starts at zero.

Comment: @realdonaldtrump Sadly, it's a matter of convention, and based on the OP's question I assume that they use $0\not\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: No. Always zero.

Comment: @realdonaldtrump That's empirically false - there are plenty of sources which define the naturals to not include $0$. If you particularly care, feel free to downvote.

Comment: Any particular reason why you used different types of delimiters here: $\bigvee_{i\in [1,\infty)}p_i$ ?

Comment: @vasili111 "if $i$ were intended to range over reals" ...